# ZoomButtonsController not attached to window manager

Tags: android

I have used a webView ,and used

```
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

but it has caused crash：

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$Container{3985b03a V.E..... ......I. 0,0-1080,146} not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:402)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:328)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:79)
at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController.setVisible(ZoomButtonsController.java:406)
at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$2.handleMessage(ZoomButtonsController.java:178)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

and my onDestroy() method is:

```
        if (null != mGraphicDetailWv) {
        mGraphicDetailSv.removeView(mGraphicDetailWv);
        mGraphicDetailWv.removeAllViews();
        mGraphicDetailWv.clearHistory();
        mGraphicDetailWv.destroy();
        mGraphicDetailWv = null;
    }
```

I don't konw how this crash happened.thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

call `mGraphicDetailWv.setVisibility(View.GONE)` before `mGraphicDetailWv.destroy()`.

This should be a issue for 23 below OS